# Javascript doesn't call my function

Tags: javascript, android, bluetooth, phonegap-plugins

I'm working on a project and i've rewritten a code to receive a bluetooth signal from an Arduino (nRF8001 shield). I've given this signal the name 'TEST123' and if this signal is in a list of Bluetooth signals my hybrid app (phonegap) should switch to another screen by calling the function showZaalScreen(). Sadly this doesn't work but I haven't been able to figure out why.

By pushing all device names in an array i should be able to filter through all device names but looking at my console log the code only gets to console.log (stap1) and then it stops working. (after stap 1 it should go to the tryloop function because I'm receiving the signal on an android).

```js
function wissel() {
  console.log('wissel');
  if (cordova.platformId === 'android') { // Android filtering is broken
    ble.scan([], tryLoop);
    console.log('stap1');
  } else {
    ble.scan([bluefruit.serviceUUID], tryLoop);
    console.log('stap2');
  }
}

function tryLoop(device) {
  console.log('tryloop');
  apparaten.push(device.name);
  for (var i = 0; i < apparaten.length; i++) {
    if (apparaten[i] == 'TEST123') {
      showZaalScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that's part of the plugin, the function to scan for bluetooth signals is called ble.scan (even thought ble isnt defined in the original code but the scan function doesnt work without it). the [] stands for the number of devices it should scan with [] meaning it doesnt have a max number of signals. -edit- i've provided the link to the plugin https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#scan

Comment: definitely true i've forgot to remove those editing the code. I immediately tried the code but sadly that doesn't make a difference. I still should've removed them though.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've updated the question.

Comment: According to the docs the success callback gets an argument, seems like you're missing device in your tryLoop function.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Javascript, could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: Right now you have `function tryLoop() {`, that should be `function tryLoop(device) {` instead.

Comment: I've tried so but the code still doesn't get to the tryLoop function.

Comment: In my console log the last message is 'stap1' and after that i get nothing

Comment: Also from the docs, it seems like the second parameter to `scan()` should be the number of seconds to run - looks like you are missing that one. I would also add the last parameter - the error callback function to see if something fails.